# Error: Validation input failed The server cannot handle directory requests

Tags: c#, active-directory, subdomain, windows-server-2016, domaincontroller

We had a application which needs user credentials for installation. Till some time back it was working fine. But all of a sudden it was throwing "**Error: Validation input failed  The server cannot handle directory requests.** " If I try the installation in a particular corporate domain  of 100 times with domain credentials, 4 times I was successful and 96 times I failed. But same installation is working fine with local domain setup(Not corporate) and some other corporate domain's also. Any hint please help us. Thanks in advance.

```
if (group.IsDomain())
        {
            if (user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(userGroup => userGroup.Name == "Administrators"))
            {
                this.MessageLog.Information("domain user is part of local Administrators '{0}'.", user.Name);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if (group.IsDomain())
            {
                if (user.GetAuthorizationGroups().Any(userGroup => userGroup.Name == "Administrators"))
                {
                    this.MessageLog.Information("domain user is part of local Administrators '{0}'.", user.Name);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {

Comment: Issue resolved after adding ContextOptions.Negotiate.  But can anyone let me know, is there any setting in system which will work without this code change.